# @synthesized properties and KVC

Tags: objective-c, kvc

Should setter generated with @synthesize be KVC compilant or not? I found statement that getters and setters generated are KVC-compliant, shouldn't it call one of this methods?

```
@interface testing : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *phone;
@end
```

implementation:

```
@implementation testing
@synthesize phone;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

// none of these is called with dot syntax, or setter setPhone
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSLog(@"%@",key);
    [super setValue:value forKey:key];
}

-(void)setValue:(id)value forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",keyPath);
    [super setValue:value forKeyPath:keyPath];
}

@end
```

and test it with:

```
testing *t = [[testing alloc] init];
[t setPhone:@"55555555"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've got it the wrong way round.. KVC compliant doesn't mean that an accessor will call `-setValue:forKey:` Being KVC compliant means that calling `-setValue:forKey:` will call the accessor.

Expanding a bit: *KVC compliant* only means '*follows naming conventions*'. Why is this important? I can call my accessor methods anything i like. For a property 'Foo':

```
- (void)weakSetFoo:(id)f;
- (id)autoreleasedFoo;
```

This is fine. But a mechanism like Bindings will try to set Foo by calling

```
[ob setValue:newVal forKey:@"foo"];
```

`-setValue:forKey:` will try to do the right thing and use the accessor method (if we wrote a setter method, it's because we want it to be used, right?). But unless we named our setter method the standard `-setFoo:` there's no way it will be found.

So `-weakSetFoo:` is a setter method, but the property Foo isn't KVC compliant.
If i change the setter name to `-setFoo:` the property Foo is now KVC compliant.

Synthesized accessor methods will by default be named correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement setValueForKey: for KVO.  It is implemented for you within the framework. By making your properties KVO compliant (which you have done using @property and @synthesize), everything just works 'magically'

----- update

Also, your testing code would not test KVO.  To test it, do something like:

```
testing *t = [[testing alloc] init];
[t setValue:@"55555555" forKey:@"phone"];
```

Comment: I'm testing statement that generated setter is KVO compilant, this is why I use setter, not setValue itselt. I know that calling setValue work, but calling generated setter not call setValue on "testing".

Answer (score 2):

It is actually the other way round. 
These are `setValue:forKey` and `getValueforKey` which look up the KVC-compliant properties, not properties synthesized through them.

When you write `@synthesize property` the compiler actually just stuffs `- (type) property` and `- (void) setProperty: (type)value` kind of methods which read/set corresponding instance variable.